# How to use the same session in two websites using ASP.Net and C# in Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net

I have two websites and i am using the same session object for both the websites.

How can i achieve the same session in two websites.

Regards,
Prasad

Comment: same session in both web sites ? please elaborate it more

Comment: For example the session["Login"] is used in Website1 and the same Session["Login"] needs to be used in the Website2 also.

Comment: directly not possible. You have to pass Session["Login"] value to other website your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The sites are seperated and as such, the Session data is seperated.

It would be a big security issue if you were able to access Session data from a remote (which this is, even though they are locally hosted) site.

Comment: But in stack overflow How can they access the user from other sites like meta.stackoverflow.com ?? Both are different websites right?

Comment: If you're talking about authentication, you can extract authentication as a separate service shared among all projects (single Sign on). You can easily and quickly achieve this using STS. What do you actually wish to share?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is basically SSO (Single Sign On), in which user is logged in to one site and isn't required to log in to other sister websites.

Either search for SSO and get detailed information on its implementation, or in both of your websites, make a webservice with enable session true.

When you need to check the session["Login"] in one website, call the web method of webservice of other website and get the information and vice versa.